# How to open div on button click in selenium Webdriver by using Java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium

MY Code is

```
<button data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="pink_button">Add Selected to Shopping List</button>
```

And my Popup Code is

```
<div class="modal-content">
            <form class="listingServes">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 id="myModalLabel" class="modal-title">Add Ingredients to Shopping List</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"><p><label for="recipe_491">Ancient Grain Pilaf with Broccoli Serves : &nbsp;</label><input type="number" value="" placeholder="Enter No. of Servings" class="drop recipe_491" rel="491" name="recipe_491"><span style="float:right;cursor:pointer;font-weight:bold" class="removeRecipe">x</span></p></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary modaladdtocart" type="button">Add to Shopping List</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

I am click on button then my Popup show but without takes any data please help me how to open my Popup on Button Click so takes proper data....
Please Help me All Tester...

Comment: Last two lines bit confusing can u explain bit clear for me

Comment: Dear Friend i found out solution....

Comment: Please close this question if you had found solution.